# How can I perform a "begin with" search in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement a text searching app using elasticsearch which performs a "begin with" search (like match_phrase_prefix), but I also need to apply some filters such as "stemmer" and "stop" on my analyser.

Here is my sample documents that I want to search against:

1. The brown fox runs quickly.
2. Watch! The brown fox is running quickly.
3. Brown foxes run quickly than yellow foxes.

And my goal is, when I searching for "brown fox", the app should return me 1) and 3)

I tried keyword as my tokeniser with filters of "stemmer" and "stop", it only worked for the last word of my document, for example:
"The brown fox runs quickly"
will become to
"the brown fox runs quick",
but I need to tokenise the whole sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply tokenization, so you will have stemming applied for each word in your sentence.

In `settings.analysis.analyzer` you could add this custom English analyzer:

```
{
  "custom_english": {
    "filter": [
      "stopwords",
      "english_possessive_stemmer",
      "lowercase",
      "english_stemmer"
    ],
    "tokenizer": "standard"
  }
}
```

Then you could add a subfield in your field definition like this in your `mappings` like this:

```
{
  "my_field": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "ignore_above": 8191,
    "fields": {
      "en": {
        "analyzer": "custom_english",
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you could query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "my_field.en": {
        "value": "brown fox"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will match 1, 3. The prefix query makes sure you only match from the beginning of the value. But when you query with `brown foxes`, then you will also get 1. That's the power of stemming.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried the "stemmer" in my filter and it does worked, but it only works on "standard" tokeniser. And the problem is the "prefix" query only work on "keyword" fields.

Comment: `match_phrase_prefix` only works on `text` fields and not `keyword` fields, so it should work.

Comment: Yes, but it works a bit different than I expected, I don't expect your query matches document #2, but it does. Is there a query that can match only from the beginning and also take the stemming / stop filters into account?

Comment: I updated my answer. In case you want to match on the beginning of the value, you need to use the prefix query.

Comment: Hey @drjz, thanks for your update, I've tried the prefix query as you suggested and also use the same analyser, but I didn't get anything back. My code can be found here 

https://gist.github.com/Jasenpan1987/93789385e890674b1e91888b4bccb651

Please advise me if I did anything wrong. Many Thanks!!!!!

Comment: I updated my answer again. You need to add the lowercase filter. Hopefully this will do the trick.